# Get error when I add new constraint in mysql

Tags: mysql, constraints

Here is my sql query for adding constraint:

ALTER TABLE cabin ADD CONSTRAINT validpriceweek CHECK (PricePerWeek<PricePerNight *5);

but it always gives me an error:
A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "CHECK" at position 48)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycCFj.png)

There is anyone can help me tell me why

Answer (score 2):

That error is coming from your client, not mysql.  You are using a client (phpmyadmin?) that foolishly tries to parse your sql before executing it.  Upgrading your client to a newer version may help; using a better client will avoid the problem.

Even then, your alter table will succeed even on older mysql versions, but before version 8.0.16 it will be ignored.

https://dbfiddle.uk/_ByDqA-M (5.7)
https://dbfiddle.uk/kKqEfxVE (8.0)